# The light grey input field boxes are not stretching from left to right when aligned to the right

Tags: html, css

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 1fr);
  gap: 0.75rem;
  width: 100%;
}

input,
textarea {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #666666;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: none;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

label {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
*First Name: <input type="text" name="myFName" id="myFName" required><br>
<label for="myFName"></label> *Last Name: <input type="text" name="myLName" id="myLName" required><br>
<label for="myLName"></label> *E-mail: <input type="email" name="myEmail" id="myEmail" required><br>
<label for="myEmail"></label> Phone information: <input type="tel" name="myPhone" id="myPhone"><br>
<label for="myPhone"></label> Graduation Date: <input type="date" id="myGraduation" name="myGraduation"><br>
<label for="myGraduation"></label> *Comments: <textarea id="myComments" name="myComments" rows="2" cols="20" required</textarea><br>
<label for="myComments"></label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="mySubmit" value="Submit">
<label for="mySubmit"></label>
```

This is what I'm getting:

https://pasteboard.co/FIk4CjHj9KGA.png

This is what I want it to look like:

https://pasteboard.co/2luiLVrDfTdW.png

Comment: I recommend you learn how to build HTML forms properly before we debug your code, because all I can see is that your code setup is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Move label text inside the label and put the label before field.
Also remove unnecessary br tags.
And put the 'required' phrase in placeholder attribute of textarea.

A raw and basic solution is like this:

```css
        form {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns:200px 1fr;
            gap: 0.75rem;
            width: 100%;
        }

        input, textarea {
            font-size: 1rem;
            padding: 10px;
            color: #666666;
            background-color: #fafafa;
            border: none;
        }

            input:focus, textarea:focus {
                outline: none;
                background-color: #f0f0f0;
                width:200px;
            }

        label {
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: right;
        }
```

```html
    <form>
        <label for="myFName">*First Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="myFName" id="myFName" placeholder="required" required>
        <label for="myLName"> *Last Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="myLName" id="myLName" placeholder="required" required>
        <label for="myEmail">*E-mail: </label>
        <input type="email" name="myEmail" id="myEmail" placeholder="required" required>
        <label for="myPhone">Phone information: </label>
        <input type="tel" name="myPhone" id="myPhone">
        <label for="myGraduation">Graduation Date: </label>
        <input type="date" id="myGraduation" name="myGraduation">
        <label for="myComments">*Comments: </label>
        <textarea id="myComments" name="myComments" rows="2" cols="20" placeholder="required" required></textarea>
        <label for="mySubmit"></label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="mySubmit" value="Submit" width="200">
    </form>
```